# How could Leah daven to change her fetus's gender?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, hashkafah-philosophy, talmud-gemara, imahot-matriarch-mothers

The gemara brachos 60a asks how could Leah daven for her fetus to change genders if the mishna calls that a wasted tefilla.
The gemara gives 2 answers.The first is, acts of miracles are different. I don't understand what this answer is saying. The mishna seems to be saying one can't daven for a miracle.

Answer (score 4):

Let’s look at what precisely the Mishnah had said:

> והצועק לשעבר הרי זו תפלת שוא היתה אשתו מעוברת ואומר יהי רצון שתלד אשתי זכר הרי זו תפלת שוא היה בא בדרך ושמע קול צוחה
> בעיר ואומר יהי רצון שלא תהא בתוך ביתי הרי זו תפלת שוא
>
> BUT TO CRY OVER THE PAST IS TO UTTER A VAIN PRAYER. IF A MAN'S WIFE IS PREGNANT AND HE SAYS, [GOD] GRANT THAT MY WIFE BEAR A MALE CHILD, THIS A VAIN PRAYER. IF HE IS COMING HOME FROM A JOURNEY AND HE HEARS CRIES OF DISTRESS IN THE TOWN AND SAYS, [GOD] GRANT THAT THIS IS NOT IN MY HOUSE, THIS IS A VAIN PRAYER.
>
> (Soncino translation, capitals in original)

The Mishnah seems to be stating a general rule, and then giving two examples of how that rule would apply in practice. The general rule is that you can’t pray for something that has already happened. The two examples of things that you can’t pray for because they have already happened are the sex of your unborn child and the who the victims in the town are.

Thus far we have seen nothing about miracles. The Mishnah is simply saying that you can’t pray for something that has already happened. It is too late to beseech God for mercy because the act is already done.

The Talmud then raises a very specific question. It does not challenge the general principle about praying for the past, nor does it being up anything about miracles. The Talmud’s question is simply that praying for the sex of your inborn child cannot be an example of this forbidden prayer, since Leah did it. The simplest explanation of this is that the Talmud has no reason to assume that the sex of the child has already been chosen, and Leah was in fact praying for the future.

The Talmud then presents two answers. The first answer retains the assumption in the Mishnah that the sex has already been chosen, and acknowledges that in most cases such a prayer would indeed be inappropriate. In this particular case, though, Leah wasn’t actually praying about the past. She acknowledged that the sex had already been chosen; she was specifically asking for a miracle to change the sex. (The miracle is to change the sex now, not to change the past.) This no longer conflicts with the Mishnah’s rule about praying for the past.

The second answer instead modifies the assumption about the sex having already been chosen. It maintains that in some cases the sex has in fact not been chosen yet, and in those cases it is indeed appropriate to pray for the sex.

Comment: Also I have seen a perush that what actually happened was that the fetuses changed places. Originally, Dinah was in Rachel's womb and Yosef was in Leah's womb. As a result of the prayer, the fetuses changed location so that Rachel gave birth to Yosef and Leah gave birth to Dinah.

Comment: The premise of the question was that if Leah was able to pray for a miracle, why can’t everyone do that? In that case, why is that the example used in the Mishnah as something in the past? It’s like praying to get better when one is sick, he’s asking to change the circumstances, even by miracle if needed.

Comment: The mishna said to daven for your wife to give birth to a son is wasted tefilla. It's not clear in those words he wants to change the past.

Comment: However if you take the mishna simply, it'll be difficult since why is it wasted tefilla, maybe it can go on next birth.

Comment: @sabbahillel The same point would stand in that version.

Comment: @Chatzkel Anyoone else praying for a miracle would presumably also not be in violation of this Mishnah. There may be other reasons, though, not to generally pray for miracles.

Comment: @Shlomy Presumably, the Mishnah does not have a problem with someone who offers a general prayer to have male children.

Comment: Whats the point of the 2nd answer.. as long as your not praying for the past there's no problem to change the gender..

Comment: @Shlomy Because the Mishnah is not talking about a miraculous case of transforming the fetus. It’s talking about a regular case where someone says “let it be a boy”. Alternatively, the second answer rejects the premise of the first answer that asking for a miracle is appropriate.

Comment: I thought you were saying the mishna is talking about changing the past. As long as you're not doing that it's not against the mishna. Thus the whole question from Leah doesn't start since she wasn't trying to change the past.

Comment: @Shlomy That’s the first answer.

Comment: I don't know where you see mishna is reffering to changing past by gender change... and where you see Leah was also (according to hava amina)

Comment: @Shlomy The Mishnah is talking about הצועק לשעבר which praying for the sex of your unborn child is an example of. According to the hava aminah that is contradicted by Leah’s practice, since the Gemara doesn’t necessarily know that there is a window of time before sex is determined, or that there was a miracle (or that it was appropriate to use a miracle).

Comment: According to your understanding the mishna never said anything against davening for a miracle.

Comment: @Shlomy Correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131403/discussion-between-shlomy-and-alex).

Comment: I think the Yerushalmi version of the same Mishnah says you can pray for the gender until the head of the baby enters the air of the world.